# Does capturing certain Pokemon require different lengths of swiping the pokeball?

Tags: pokemon-go

There's something I noticed while playing Pokemon Go. Certain Pokemon appear to require shorter or longer swipes when capturing. For example, I have to use a shorter swipe for Pidgey and Rattata or else I overshoot the pokeball. On in-air and evolved-form Pokemon, like Zubat (in-air) and Arcanine (evolved), I often undershoot and have to swipe very far to make sure the pokeball hits the Pokemon. Has anyone noticed this too?

I'm wondering if certain Pokemon fall under the same swipe category, for example: short-swipe Pokemon like Pidgey and Rattata that require the same exact length. I can't find documentation on this from Niantic, but of course, they have barely documented anything anyway. But otherwise, it might just depend on the individual Pokemon?

Comment: I think the Pokemon is further away if it is a higher CP. I found a 900 pidgeot where 90% of my throws didnt even reach because he was so far back.

Comment: I feel like it's really confusing, because in some circumstances they don't really _appear_ to be further away, it's just that your pokeball falls like a rock once you release it. It can be very frustrating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes different types of pokemon are a different "distance" away from your pokeball. Flying pokemon such as zubats require a longer throw while small pokemon such as weedles and caterpies tend to require shorter distances. Other larger ground pokemon tend to be in between these two distances. CP also has some effect on distance where a higher CP weedle is further away than a lower CP weedle.

Also for whatever reason Pidgies and Spearows don't really fly so they can also be really close to the pokeball.

Source: Personal experience

Comment: Yes, Pokémon with higher CP tend to be further away from what I've experienced. I almost had to shoot a 800 CP Hypno because it was almost too far away to throw a ball at it.